# Samsung Galaxy S5 mini dies suddenly

Tags: system-freeze, samsung-galaxy-s-5-mini

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 mini which is two months old. I have the following problem:

The phone suddenly becomes unresponsive, the screen goes black and it does not give any signs of 'life'. Pushing any button does not do anything. Keeping the power button 7sec for the device to power off is not working. The only solution to 'revive' the device is to pull off the battery.

While in this state, notifications, alarms, calls etc are not working.

- I do not know if this is the right place to ask such a question, so sorry
  if I am out of topic.
- This is NOT a duplicate of [Samsung Galaxy S5 died suddenly and without reason!](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85656/help-samsung-galaxy-s5-died-suddenly-and-without-reason)

Comment: Honestly I'd go back to the seller and get a replacement. It could be a number of things, but with a device that new I'd get a replacement or refund.

Comment: Have you solved your issue meanwhile? If so, would be nice to let us know. Remember you can always [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154) ;)

Comment: @Izzy The problem is very rare after a factory reset and after applying some of the official Samsung software updates, but I can not say that it was resolved

Comment: So you still have those "freezes"?

Comment: Yes, the 'freezes' are still there but they do not happen as often as they used to. Last time I had encountered a 'freeze' was almost three months ago.